# Round numbers to closest 10's in Angular

Tags: angular, pipe, rounding

How can I use the angular pipe `number` to round a value to the closest 10's unit?

For example, the following numbers to the left should be converted to the corresponding numbers to the right:

```
1     ->   0
11.5  ->  10
22.2  ->  20
44    ->  40
```